# Count values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys i need some helps in terms of query. I have a table which consists of many columns which get the same results from data like 'overdue','At-risk','NA'.

How do i count like examples 'At-risk' from different columns in to one.

For examples:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  1_status1 | 1_status2 | 1_status3        |
|  NA        | at-risk   | at-risk          |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101941/count-number-of-distinct-rows-for-multiple-values

Comment: What do you mean by "count different columns into one?"  Do you just want a count of all the occurrences?

Comment: @Siyual That was how interpreted the question when I changed the title... hope I didn't misrepresent the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a count of the number of times 'at-risk' occurs across all rows and columns, one way to do this would be to pivot the table (turn it around on its axis) using a set of union all statements and then do a normal count query.

This query:

```
select value, count(*) as "count"
from 
(
    select '1_status1' as type, "1_status1" as value from t
    union all
    select '1_status2' as type, "1_status2" as value from t
    union all
    select '1_status3' as type, "1_status3" as value from t
) a
--where value = 'at-risk' -- uncomment to limit the count to 'at-risk'
group by value
```

would, given your data, give this result:

```
value    count
at-risk  2
NA       1
```

Comment: thanks for providing me the answer to my problem it works thanks a lot sorry for the phrasing of words which i am a bit weak in .

Answer (score 0):

I'll update this if this isn't what you're looking for (your requirement is rather vague in terms of what you're looking for).  But you can just do a `Union All` for all the columns and run a `Count` aggregate on the results:

```
Select  Status, Count(*) Count
From
(
    Select  `1_status1` As Status
    From    Table 
    Union All
    Select  `1_status2` As Status
    From    Table
    Union All
    Select  `1_status3` As Status
    From    Table
) As A
Group by Status
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot for the answers sorry for the bad phrasing of question thnaks alot for the help